# SQL Server data tools derived column

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

My SQL teacher converted an Excel file to a `.csv` file

My problem is that the `.csv` file has changed the date values (`dd-mm-yy`) to strange numbers. This is a big problem because my SQL Server database needs a date value not a strange number + characters. I am using SISS to solve this problem, but I don't know how to fix it. I am quite new to SSIS.

Date example in CSV: `41640`

Date example in SSIS dataviewer: `1;1;41640;41641;41646` (strange code instead of a date)

My SQL teacher says that we must use a derived column for this problem, he was also talking about the Pivot and the Unpivot tools. Can you guys be so kind to give us some examples how to solve this with a derived column?

I can't post any images to make it more clear what a mean. Because I need 10 reputation to post images :(

I am using the flat file source to call my `.csv`, then I have placed a empty derived column (to solve the `.csv` date problem). After that I have a `Date` conversion, followed by a derived column (used to TRIM the new data)

I hope that you guys can help me out!

Comment: Those 416xx numbers look very like Excel dates. Is your data coming from Excel? What data type are the incoming columns defined by in SSIS?

Comment: The dates are converted from Excel to a csv file. So yes my dates are coming from a csv. (excel) file. I use the data type string [DT_STR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ad a step adding derived or calculated columns. In the column that contains e.g. 41640 I will assume that column name is xyz.

The new calculated column will use the formula `DateAdd(DD, [xyz], '31 Dec 1899')` and be a DT_DATE type.

For excel, a date od 1 Jan 1900 is represented by the number 1. So you need to convert these numbers to a date. I'm not 100% sure of the formula syntax as I don't have SSIS on this machine.